# How to make enqueue_embed_scripts work with the embed_template filter

Tags: embed, oembed

I am currently trying to customize the display of my posts that gets embedded on other sites.

I am able to have my custom template file through the `embed_template` filter but I can't successfully enqueue scripts if I am using the embed template. The filter `enqueue_embed_scripts` works without problem if I am not using the `embed_template` filter. I also tried the `embed_head` and `embed_footer` hooks but I can't get them to work as well.

This is my current code:

```
class Test_Embed {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'enqueue_embed_scripts', array( $this, 'embed_styles' ) );
        add_filter( 'embed_template', array( $this, 'my_embed_template' ) );     

    }

    public function embed_styles() { 


        wp_enqueue_style( 'myb-css', plugin_dir_url( dirname( dirname( __FILE__) ) ) . 'public/css/public.css', array(), '', 'all' );
    }



   public function my_embed_template( $template ) {

        if ( 'custom-post' === get_post_type() ) {
            return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/templates/my-template.php'; 
        }

        return $template;

    }


}

new Test_Embed;
```

Is there something I missed in enqueuing scripts to the custom embed template I am using?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use Fancybox? Keep in mind that the embedded post is inside an iframe, and you're not going to be able to launch a lightbox outside the bounds of that post preview.

Comment: Thanks! Though it is not really my main concern for now as I am not able to enqueue and CSS and JS files.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I just overlooked adding the `do_action( 'embed_head' )` and `do_action( 'embed_footer' )` in the template file that I have.

Teehee!